# IOS Google Maps Sample Code provides error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have Tried creating Google Map using Google Map SDK.

I have added all the library mentioned by the Google & Also implemented the sample code 
`[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyAEu3QMEC5-KdE1VdLw8K2u-z6dZqXLvzw"];` in AppDelegate

And

```
@implementation ViewController{
     GMSMapView *mapView_;
}
and

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20
                                                                 zoom:6];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = mapView_;

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
    marker.title = @"Sydney";
    marker.snippet = @"Australia";
    marker.map = mapView_;`
```

in the ViewController.m file. And also added `-ObjC` in the buildphases file of the project Still getting the same error i.e. `-[GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent` .

Here is the trace

```
`2014-12-24 16:40:36.635 YourLocalBookShop[2501:188298] -[GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7aedd350
2014-12-24 16:40:36.659 YourLocalBookShop[2501:188298] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7aedd350'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02139946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01dc2a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x021415c5 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0208a3e7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02089fae _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   YourLocalBookShop                   0x00235772 -[GMSMapView setCamera:] + 187
    6   YourLocalBookShop                   0x00233b01 -[GMSMapView sharedInitWithServices:camera:] + 2029
    7   YourLocalBookShop                   0x00232cb5 -[GMSMapView initWithFrame:camera:] + 122
    8   YourLocalBookShop                   0x00232b66 +[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:camera:] + 93
    9   YourLocalBookShop                   0x000923f7 -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 247
    10  UIKit                               0x028582a4 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 771
    11  UIKit                               0x02858595 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    12  UIKit                               0x0274f825 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
    13  UIKit                               0x0274fc99 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 287
    14  UIKit                               0x0274ff50 -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    15  UIKit                               0x0275e28d -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 80
    16  UIKit                               0x026fb776 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3108
    17  UIKit                               0x026fec0d -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1639
    18  UIKit                               0x027177d0 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 59
    19  UIKit                               0x026fd81f -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 155
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x066f99de __37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71
    21  FrontBoardServices                  0x066f946f __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 54
    22  FrontBoardServices                  0x0670b425 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 26
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0205d1c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x02052ad3 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0205292b __CFRunLoopRun + 2715
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x02051bcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x020519fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    28  UIKit                               0x026fd1e4 -[UIApplication _run] + 571
    29  UIKit                               0x027008b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    30  YourLocalBookShop                   0x00092afd main + 141
    31  libdyld.dylib                       0x03a4aac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) `
```

Comment: Where do you use animateToCameraPosition?

Comment: Another important note: you should add the flag -ObjC in the targets of you application not in the project. This could be the problem

Comment: Hey Sawsan I have mentioned it clearly i have added it to Project and not target I have folllowed the same sample code & steps as mentioned by Google Docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried again with all steps mentioned at Google Developers Guide and was able to make it work. I guess i might have missed out somewhere in adding the frameworks listed or might have missed out somewhere in linking those frameworks